# Difference between AMP and AMQP?

Tags: python, twisted, iot, amqp

The Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) and the Asynchronous Messaging Protocol (AMP), as their name already says, are protocols.

I can't really find a difference between the two. It seems like AMQP is more popular and widely used than AMP, which was mainly built with [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

If the lack of use of AMP is the case, should AMP be considered a more toy-like implementation and thus AMQP be the preferable choice?

Comment: I'm not sure, what about this? https://amp-protocol.net/ (Nevermind the comment I was replying to was deleted) Edit2: Indeed, typing `amp` in google won't show the amp protocol page.

Comment: Those two have little in common except the 3 letters in the name. In fact, if you google for AMP you get Google's [AMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Mobile_Pages) proposal, mainly used in HTML emails. Despite the assertions, [*that* AMP](https://amp-protocol.net/) is simply the protocol used by Twisted. AMQP on the other hand is a queueing protocol implemented in multiple languages, provided by multiple vendors, including *cloud* vendors and widely used in IoT

Comment: In fact, even Twisted's AMP site says it's a remoting protocol, not a queueing protocol. If you want a trendy RPC protocol, why not gRPC?

Comment: Isn't AMP also implemented in other languages? According to you, that would also make it a protocol. https://amp-protocol.net/implementations.html

Comment: Oh got it, so the main difference lays with AMP being a remote protocol and AMQP a queueing protocol!

Comment: And that AMP isn't used for RPC by anyone except Twisted. If you want RPC, try gRPC

Comment: Excellent thanks! If you want to elaborate the answer I will gladly mark it as the best one! :)